# chrome blocking the cookies even with samesite=None

Tags: google-chrome, flask, cookies, samesite

I have a flask application hosted in heroku embedded as an iframe to one of my website.
Let's say `a.com` renders this `<heroku_url>.com` as an iframe.
When user visits `a.com`, `<heroku_url>.com` is rendered and session is created.

```
from flask import session, make_response

@app.route("/")
def index():
    session['foo'] = 'bar'
    response = make_response("setting cookie")
    response.headers.add('Set-Cookie', 'cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure')
    return response
```

In Chrome dev tools, I see the cookie getting blocked. Works fine in firefox though.
Am I setting the cookie properly?
I understand this is due to chrome80 update, but not sure about the workaround

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `samesite` attribute in the session cookie to `None` seems to have solved the problem.

Had to update `werkzeug` (WSGI web application library which is wrapped by flask) and update the session cookie.
i.e

```
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
```

However, this also depends on the user's preference in 'chrome://settings/cookies'.

Chrome will block the session cookies even if `samesite` is set to None if one of the below options is selected

- Block third-party cookies
- Block all cookies
- Block third-party cookies in Incognito (blocks in incognito mode).

Comment: Really solve my problem when trying to Login in a Laravel application in an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your browser is treating the cookies as expected by checking the test site at https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me/

If all the rows contain green checks (✔️) then there it's likely there is some kind of issue with the cookie and I would suggest checking the Issues tab and Network tab in DevTools to confirm the `set-cookie` header definitely contains what it should.

If there are any red or orange crosses (✘) on the test site, then something in your browser is affecting cookies. Check that you are not blocking third-party cookies (`chrome://settings/cookies`) or running an extension that may do something similar.